# Get Dropdown Value in Meteor Js?

Tags: meteor

I did one sample **Search**app using meteor add sebdah:autocompletion package.When ever given inputs it shows drop down list.In this list how to get selected value as shown below code:

Js Code :

```
    Friends = new Meteor.Collection('friends');

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  /**
   * Template - search
   */
  Template.search.rendered = function () {
    AutoCompletion.enableLogging = true;
   var res =  AutoCompletion.init("input#searchBox");

   console.log("res :"+res);

  }

  Template.search.events = {
    'keyup input#searchBox': function (e,t) {

      AutoCompletion.autocomplete({
        element: 'input#searchBox',       // DOM identifier for the element
        collection: Friends,              // MeteorJS collection object
        field: 'name',                    // Document field name to search for
        limit: 0,                         // Max number of elements to show
        sort: {name: 1}
      });

    }
  }
}
```

I didn't get any idea about this.So please suggest me how to get selected drop down list values?

Answer (score 0):

`AutoCompletion` package doesn't give any good API to read value on select.  Instead you need to manually read the value of `input#searchBox`.
Please take a look at [source code](https://github.com/sebdah/meteor-autocompletion/blob/master/sebdah:autocompletion/autocompletion.js).

I would recommend to implement searching in your meteor app using Arunoda's approach : https://meteorhacks.com/implementing-an-instant-search-solution-with-meteor.html

Comment: is there any example code for search in search-source package?.@Kuba Wyrobek.

Comment: If you read carefully the article about search-source you will discover that it is tutorial showing how to build search feature in your app. Additionally there is link to [demo app](https://github.com/meteorhacks-samples/meteor-instant-search-demo) source code